# How to show that $y_K< 4?$

Tags: functional-analysis

$X = C[0,1]$. $$x_n(t) =
\begin{cases}
nt,  & \text{for $0 \leq t \leq \frac{1}{n}$ } \\
2-nt, & \text{for $\frac{1}{n} \leq t \leq \frac{2}{n}$ }  \\
0, & \text{for $\frac{2}{n} \leq t \leq 1$}  \\
\end{cases}$$

Prove that $x_n$ tend to zero weak  but not strongly ?

**My attempt** : Proof is given in the  book  Functional analysis by **Peter D . Lax**  courant institute

Here is an outline of the proof

> let $l$ be  a bounded  linear  function
> we claim that $l(x_n)=0$ when $n \to \infty$
> Now suppose that $l(x_n)\neq0$ when $n \to \infty$, then there  would be infinitely  many $n$  such that $|l(x_n)|> \delta >0$ say $l(x_n) > \delta.$
> choose  a subsequence ${n_k}, n_{k+1} >2n_k$  for which $l(x_n) > \delta$ hold. It is not hard to show that for all $t$ in $[0,1] $

> $y_K= \sum_{1}^{K}x_{n_k}(t)  < 4\tag1$

> which implies that $|y_K|< 4$ for all $K$.From $(1)$ it follow that
> $l(y_K)=\sum_{1}^{K}l(x_n) > K\delta$

> Since this holds for all $K$ , and since |$y_K| <4$ for all $K$ , the boundedness of $l$ is contradicted.
> Since $|x_n|=\max_n(t)=1$
> $\{x_n\}$ does not tend to zero strongly

**My confusion** :  why $y_K= \sum_{1}^{K}x_{n_k}(t) < 4?$  why does the author put series in $y_K$ ?

My thinking : Here $x_n(t) $ is a  sequence  but not a series.

Suppose $ y_K$ is series  then

$y_K= \sum_{1}^{K}x_{n_k}(t) = x_{n_1}(t) + x_{n_2}(t)+...........+x_{n_{k+1}}(t)= \underbrace{ 1+1+.....+1}_{K \text{times}}= K  >4$

Comment: He is defining $y_K$ as that sum involving the terms of the subsequence of $(x_n)_n$ constructed previously, there is no trick in doing that. On the other hand, $x_{n_k}$ is not necessarily equal to $1$ for all $k$, it depends on which $t\in [0, 1]$ you are taking. Have you tried to prove the statement by induction or something?

Comment: @rebo79  i didn't use induction. Im thinking that  $x_n(t) =nt =1$ because   if we take $n=2$ then $t=1/2 $ similarly for $3,4......$.


$x_n(t) =2-nt =2-1=1$ because   if we take $n=2$ then $t=1/2 $ similarly for $3,4.....$


.$x_n(t) =nt =0$

So $y_K= \sum_{1}^{K}x_{n_k}(t) = x_{n_1}(t) + x_{n_2}(t)+...........+x_{n_{k+1}}(t)= \underbrace{ 1+1+.....+1+0+0..+0}_{K \text{times}}= K$

Comment: Observe that the $n_k$'s are not arbitrary, indeed the subsequence that he constructed satisfies $n_{k+1}>2n_k$ for all $k$, then the sum $\sum_k x_{n_k}(t)$ depends strongly on $t\in [0, 1]$ (you may consider the "overlap" induced by the property of $n_k$).